# How can I return rows where only duplicates within a certain column exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose that my database looks something like the following:

```
First Entry | Second Entry | Third Entry
    0              0              0
    0              1              2
    2              1              0 
    2              0              1
    3              0              0
```

I am trying to return the subset of this table where an element in the `FirstEntry` column repeats at least once. So in this case it would return all but the final row. How can I go about this? I've tried using things such as `count()` but have only managed to achieve grouping instead of returning the actual rows I am curious in (in particular, I care aboout Second and Third entry but only when First entry has repeated at least once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `IN()`

```
select * from your_table
where FirstEntry in
(
   select FirstEntry 
   from your_table
   group by FirstEntry 
   having count(*) > 1
)
```

or using a `JOIN`

```
select t1.* 
from your_table t1
join
(
   select FirstEntry 
   from your_table
   group by FirstEntry 
   having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t1.FirstEntry = t2.FirstEntry
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from my_table
where First_Entry IN(SELECT First_Entry From my_table 
group by First_entry having count(*) > 1)
```